# word problem, please help

Tags: graphing-functions

> Your classmate Juan missed the lesson on graphing linear  equations using slope-intercept form. You attend the class and what to help Juan understand the material he missed. Assume Juan knows how to graph $y=x$.
>
> Part A: Write an explanation for Juan that describes the y-intercept of a line and what happens to the graph of $y=x$ as you change the y-intercept. Be specific and consider several cases.
>
> Part B: Write an explanation for Juan that describes the slope $m$ of a line  and what happens to the graph of $y=x$ as you change the slope. Be specific and consider several cases.

well here it it seems hard right... well it does to me , I really don't know what to do

Comment: What do you mean by word problem ? You want the solution in just words ?

Comment: no it doesn't matter I just want the solution please, if you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y=x$ is a line passing through origin, with a slope of $1$.

**Part:A**

Here we are just changing the y-intercept, so the slope remains same. So if we keep on changing the y-intercept, we get lines which are parallel to $y=x$.

All the lines with a positive y-intercept lie to the left of the line $y=x$, i.e., in the second quadrant.

**Part:B**

Here we are just changing the slope of the line $y=x$. So in general let the slope be $m$. Since the line still passes through origin, because we are only changing the slope, the equation of the new line would be $y=mx$.

To get a more clear understanding of this, just take a pen hold it firmly at the center and rotate it in any which direction you want. The same thing happens in in Part:B.

Comment: Thank you thank you so much  !!!